# Will i get the entire document from the firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: my firestore structure]

hi. i have a database as in the picture above
i have a smartphones collection with many documents(i.e. iphone or xiaomi) inside.
i will use react to render this information and i want to load it from part to part.
i.e. i want to render all of the smartphones on the main page and filter them... so for the main page i will only need description and ratings and for the full product details i will need tech specs and reviews.
imagine that the whole document weight is 1mb
100kb both descriptions 200kb for tech specs 400kb reviews and 200kb ratings
my question is:

1. if i want to load only ratings and short description for the main page of 100 products. can i get only 300kb data from each product or i will get the whole 100mb data ???
2. if i want to edit only camera 64mpx .. can i do this without getting all the document from the DB?
3. is there any easy tool to add/edit/remove data in the firestore DB like MongoDBCompass ?
4. any information about how read/add/edit operations works in firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i want to load only ratings and short description for the main page of 100 products

You can load only `ratings` as it's a document on it's own document. You cannot load only `short description` as you cannot fetch a single field from a document. You'll get both `short description` and `full description` fields. (Do note that this won't include documents from the sub-collections i.e. reviews, tech specs in this case)

> if i want to edit only camera 64mpx .. can i do this without getting all the document from the DB?

As long as you know ID of that document (smartphone document), you can using following update operation:

```js
const phoneRef = firebase.firestore().collection("smartphones").doc("smart_phone_id")

const mediaRef = phoneRef.collection("tech_specs").doc("media")
mediaRef.update({ camera: "108px" })
```

> is there any easy tool to add/edit/remove data in the firestore DB like MongoDBCompass ?

Firebase's console (where the screenshot is from) is one but there isn't any one click import built natively.

Comment: so the idea is that i can get only document with it fields without getting the whole document right? i.e. i can get a document fields in 10 step collection depth.. ? so i must store everything i want to get separately in the collections right?
but if i want to reverse? to get the whole document tree ?

Comment: @GArthur you cannot fetch a single field from document. If you fetch a document, you get it completely. You don't get the 'sub-collections'. If you divide all the data in sub-collection/documents then yes you can get selected data but do note that it is costing you 1 read for every part. To get the whole data, you need to make separate requests for each part and each of them will cost 1 read.

Comment: In my opinion, realtime db sounds a better alternative for such structure since you can request a specific part and also the complete node in a single request.